# PyS60 application not going full screen

Tags: python, symbian, pys60

I am very new to PyS60. I was testing how to set an application to full screen mode but unfortunately, it doesn't work as expected. I tested the script on Nokia 6120 Classic. Here is what I did:

`appuifw.app.screen = 'full'`

What I get is a half screen of my application with a plain white colour below. What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could try also asking in Forum Nokia's Python forum: http://discussion.forum.nokia.com/forum/forumdisplay.php?f=102

Answer (score 4):

Make sure you define own functions for **screen redraw** and **screen rotate** callbacks. When you rotate the device, you have to manually rescale everything to fit the new screen size. Otherwise you might get that "half of screen" effect.

```
    canvas = img = None

    def cb_redraw(aRect=(0,0,0,0)):
        ''' Overwrite default screen redraw event handler '''
        if img:
            canvas.blit(img)

    def cb_resize(aSize=(0,0,0,0)):
        ''' Overwrite default screen resize event handler '''
        global img
        img = graphics.Image.new(canvas.size)

    appuifw.app.screen = 'full'
    canvas = appuifw.Canvas(
        resize_callback = cb_resize,
        redraw_callback = cb_redraw)
    appuifw.app.body = canvas
```

Comment: I had just this problem and your solution works perfectly. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't already, I would advise using the latest version of PyS60 from https://garage.maemo.org/frs/?group_id=854 and trying again.

Do the other two screen modes work as they are supposed to?